# Read an .xlsx file and copy contents to another workbook

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to read the contents of one Excel file and copy that into another workbook. Here is the code I tried but it is not working:

```vb
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Excel\Book2.xlsx"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim WriteToRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strCurrentTxtFile As String
    Dim xlExcelApp  As Excel.Application
    Dim xlImportWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlManRange As Excel.Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Start from Row 1
    WriteToRow = 1

    strCurrentTxtFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")

    '~~> Looping through all text files in a folder
    Do While strCurrentTxtFile <> ""

        '~~> Open the file in 1 go to read it into an array
        Set xlExcelApp = New Excel.Application
        Set xlImportWorkbook = xlExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        Set xlManRange = xlImportWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A1:A20")

        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1

        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        '~~> Read from the array and write to Excel
        For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
            ws.Range("A" & WriteToRow).Value = strData(i)
            WriteToRow = WriteToRow + 1
        Next i

        strCurrentTxtFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.